# How to add "arrow-down" triangle with CSS to responsive tabs

Tags: css

I'm using [Responsive tabs](http://www.petelove.com/responsiveTabs/) by [petelove666](https://github.com/petelove666/Responsive-Tabs) and I have a small detail I'd like to add but it seems I can not get it to work.

I would like a arrow-down formed by triangle at the middle of active tab.

I tried to change CSS to

```css
.responsive-tabs__list__item--active{
    background: white;
    color: #3E4649;
    /*border-bottom: 2px solid #F39114;*/
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: solid 20px #F39114;
    border-left: solid 5px transparent;
    border-right: solid 5px transparent;
}
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Here is my fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/dvx8nw15/. And the goal is to have a down arrow at the middle of active tab as seen from the attached picture with blue color:
[image]

Comment: Can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: @AkhileshBChandran: Just added fiddle!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is to add an absolutely centered triangle to `list__item`:

```
.responsive-tabs__list__item { position: relative }

.responsive-tabs__list__item--active:after {
    content: '';
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    border-left: 10px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid transparent;
    border-top: 10px solid black;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
}
```

And the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jug9m4o7/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `list-style-type` from the list items and add a div that will be your arrow. The triangle trick is to set an element with size 0 but to set a border, the top border in that case is actually a triangle, so when you give it a color and set the other side to be transparent you'll get a triangle.

```css
li{
  list-style-type:none;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.arrow{
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #F39114;
  margin-top: 0.2em;
  margin-right: 0.2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><div class="arrow"></div>One</li>
  <li><div class="arrow"></div>Two</li>
  <li><div class="arrow"></div>Three</li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE**

Adding a fiddle without adding a div and using :before pseudo element instead

[Example with your code](https://jsfiddle.net/dvx8nw15/3/)

You need to add class `arrow` to each li you want to style or otherwise add it to the container once and then set `.arrow li` instead of `li.arrow`

[Second example - better since you don't need to style each li](https://jsfiddle.net/dvx8nw15/4/)

Comment: Just to let you know: I added fiddle.

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: This adds triangles everywhere. I want it only at the bottom and in the middle of currently active tab.

Comment: I'm sorry but looks to me like we are having some communication problems. Have you seen the picture attached to the OP? So what I'm trying to do is leave the content inside the tab as is (so no changes to the lists) but make it more visually obvious which tab is currently active.  For example attached picture: clicking the "How to use" tab, makes it active. Because this tab is now active I want to have a blue down arrow at the bottom of the tab pointing towards the content. I don't need or want any of these arrows inside the content of a tab.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position: relative` to your `li.responsive-tabs__list__item`. And then use a pseudoclass to print the arrow in your active item with this code:

```css
.responsive-tabs__list__item--active:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: black;
    margin-left: -10px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You can find an example in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dvx8nw15/5/)